# ASP.NET Core web app template with authentication type "Individual Accounts"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I created an ASP.NET Core web app with authentication type "Individual Accounts" in Visual Studio.

When I log out from the app, I can see the cookie being removed from browser. If I manually add this cookie in browser after I log out from the app, it still considers me as logged in.

So on the server side there is no tracking of active logins in ASP.NET Core identity? Or on log out, does the server know I have logged out? It is only the removal of cookie from browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the logout is just remove the from browser. The server don't know the user has logged out.

When the client browser access the application it will add the cookie, the server will just check the cookie.

The cookie contains the expire time, the server will just check the expire time, if the expire time is not exceed, the cookie is still worked.